# Comparing specific values in Dictionary key

Tags: swift

I have struct that I use for Dictionary key:

```
struct MyKey {
  let name: String
  let flag: Bool
}
```

What I want is, to change the "`flag`" property and still being able to find a value specified by that key. Here is complete playground example:

```
struct MyKey {
  let name: String
  let flag: Bool
}

extension MyKey: Hashable {
  static func == (lhs: MyKey, rhs: MyKey) -> Bool {
      return lhs.name == rhs.name
  }
}

var fKey = MyKey(name: "fKey", flag: false)
var sKey = MyKey(name: "sKey", flag: true)

var dictFirst: [MyKey: String] = [fKey: "fValue",
                                  sKey: "sValue"]
var dictSecond: [MyKey: String] = [fKey: "fValue",
                                   sKey: "sValue"]

let changedFKey = MyKey(name: "fKey", flag: true)

print(dictFirst[changedFKey]) // Prints nil, want it to be fValue
```

In fact, in extension I tried to specify that I only cares about "`name`", but still It's not work as intended

Answer (score 1):

You also have to implement hash value correctly, the generated hash takes `flag` into account:

```
extension MyKey: Hashable {
  static func == (lhs: MyKey, rhs: MyKey) -> Bool {
      return lhs.name == rhs.name
  }

  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
     hasher.combine(name)
  }
}
```

However, in principle this is bad design. If the `flag` does not affect the key, it shouldn't be part of the key. It would be better to index by `name` directly.

Comment: thanks! I wonder why it's not obliged to do so while use it as washable..

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Both `Equatable` and `Hashable` (which inherites from `Equatable`) are generated automatically for you. In 99% of the cases you want all properties to affect equality and hash value and that's what the generated implementation does.